# Using pandas.read_csv for csv's capturing non-mutually exclusive categories in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I want to create a csv file where column 1 is an index, column 2 is some category listing, for example, column 1 is people I know, and column 2 is type: (relative, friend, professional acquaintence)

But in some situations someone might be both a professional acquaintance and a friend, or a relative and a friend, or even all three.

Is there a way I can store this data in a csv file so that when I load it into pandas as a dataframe I can then group the data by relative, or friend, or professional acquaintance, allowing for double or triple-counting the same person and later to counts and stuff related to this?  This is my question. I want to know how to deal with this situation.

Example INPUT:

charlie is a professional acquaintance and friend

todd is a relative and friend

jess is a professional acquaintance

tom is a professional acquaintence

Example OUTPUT: (by running the `dfFromCSV.groupby('type').size()`)

professional acquaintences: 3

friend: 2

relative: 1

Comment: do you have an exhaustive list of relationship types *a priori*?

Answer (score 1):

Assume your input is stored in a dataframe called `df` is formatted as follows:

```
person   type
john     friend+work
jack     work
judy     college
janet    friend+work
jean     friend
```

The only requirement is that you have a separator, in this case `'+'`. What you can do is the following:

```
df['type'].str.split('+').str.join(sep='+').str.get_dummies(sep='+').sum(axis=0)
```

Output:

```
college    1
friend     3
work       3
```

You can have as many categories as you want, no need to know them in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list of relationships is exhaustive, you can brute-force it like this:

```
import pandas
from io import StringIO

csvstring = StringIO("""\
relationship
charlie is a professional acquaintance and friend
todd is a relative and friend
jess is a professional acquaintance
tom is a professional acquaintance
""")

rtypes = [
    'professional acquaintance',
    'friend',
    'relative',
    'rival',
    'nemsis',
    'mortal enemy'
]

df = pandas.read_csv(csvstring)
for rt in rtypes:
    df[rt] = df['relationship'].apply(lambda x: int(rt in x))

df.select_dtypes(exclude=[object]).sum()
```

Which gives me:

```
professional acquaintance    3
friend                       2
relative                     1
rival                        0
nemsis                       0
mortal enemy                 0
dtype: int64
```

Note that you have a spelling error in your example, and this method won't catch those.